# How do I assign a delegate in a view for a control contained in a child view?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uisearchbar

I have a view controller which contains a UISearchBar

```
@interface TradeFindHeaderViewController_iPhone : UIViewController {
  UISearchBar *searchBar;
}

#pragma mark - Properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

#pragma mark - Methods
-(void) configureSearchBar;

@end
```

This controller is then initialized and stored in a property of another controller.

```
@interface TradeFindViewController_iPhone : TradeFindViewController<UISearchBarDelegate>         {
  TradeFindHeaderViewController_iPhone *_headerController;
}

#pragma mark - Properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) TradeFindHeaderViewController_iPhone *headerController;

@end
```

I want this TradeFindViewController_iPhone to receive the UISearchBar delegate events so I assign it's delegate

```
-(void)configureTableHeader{

  self.headerController=[[TradeFindHeaderViewController_iPhone alloc]initWithNibName:@"TradeFindHeaderView_iPhone" bundle: nil];
  self.headerController.searchBar.delegate=self;
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView=self.headerController.view;

}
```

However, the UISearchBar delegate events are not being called. Have I assigned the delegate properly given the UISearchBar is in the contained view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably implement a multi-level delegate system. Your TradeFindHeaderViewController_iPhone class would register as the delegate for the UISearchBar, and would then call a delegate method in your TradeFindViewController_iPhone class.

This solution helps to keep the whole design very modular, and also prevents things breaking (changing the name of objects) across classes.

This should solve your issue with the delegate methods not being called.

Hope this was of some help.

Josh